# SQL Wild Cards Selection

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a column called `memo` under `transaction` table. I am looking for memos with keywords like 'PAYROLL' but not contains a single word 'PAY'.

```
SELECT DISTINCT memo FROM transaction WHERE memo LIKE '%PAYROLL%'
```

The query above could only finds those memo with "PAYROLL" within it. However, how can I exclude 'PAY'?

Comment: `AND memo <> 'PAY'`?  You shouldn't even need this - the `LIKE` statement would already filter that out.

Comment: Actually you query will never select a record with just `PAY`

Comment: PAY can be at the very end?.. I mean you can exclude `'PAY '`, but if the phrase ends with it, it wont have space, so It's not clear how to generalize sinle word here

Comment: Please, show an sample of column `memo`.

Answer (score 1):

That should be possible with regular expressions: Exclude strings that contain 'PAY' with both a leading and trailing non-alphanumeric character. (You'll have to add such a character, e.g. `'.'`, to the start and end of your string for the check to work.)

```
SELECT DISTINCT memo 
FROM transaction 
WHERE memo LIKE '%PAYROLL%'
AND '.' || memo || '.' !~ '[^[:alnum:]]PAY[^[:alnum:]]';
```

As Tim Biegeleisen mentioned in a comment below, PostgreSQL's regexp supports word boundaries. That makes the expression much simpler and we dont have to add the dots at the end and start of memo anymore:

```
SELECT DISTINCT memo 
FROM transaction 
WHERE memo LIKE '%PAYROLL%' AND memo !~ '\mPAY\M';
```

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen: Yes and yes. I've never worked with regexp word boundaries and didn't know they were available. I'll update my answer accordinlgy. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT memo
FROM transaction
WHERE memo LIKE '%PAYROLL%' AND
      memo NOT LIKE 'PAY %'  AND
      memo NOT LIKE '% PAY %' AND
      memo NOT LIKE '% PAY'
```

This will find memos containing the *substring* `PAYROLL` which also do not contain the word `PAY`.  If you actually want to check for standalone words, it will take more work.  Regex might be helpful in that case.

Comment: You need to add spaces to isolate pay as a word, otherwise you get PAYROLL, like `'% PAY %'`

Comment: Give an example where this fails.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen When the `memo` is `'PAYROLL'`?

Comment: @MarcosSilva Wrong.  The word could be the first or last entry in the column.

Comment: Sorry everyone...I failed to see that `PAY` is contained in `PAYROLL`.  Nominated for sloppy answer of the hour.

Comment: using `NOT LIKE` without the wildcards is just using `<>`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT memo FROM transaction WHERE memo::tsvector @@ 'PAYROLL & !PAY'::tsquery;
```

Maybe make use of PostgreSQL's text search.